# how to extract required data from mysql text column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Hi i have a mysql table which contains data like below

```
mysql> select * from query limit 5\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
text:   <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-08-20T14:07:41" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="12427041" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="/* mysql-connector-java-5.1.18 ( Revision: tonci.grgin@oracle.com-20110930151701-jfj14ddfq48ifkfq ) */SELECT @@session.auto_increment_increment"/> 
*************************** 2. row ***************************
text:   <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-08-20T14:07:41" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="12427032" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="/* mysql-connector-java-5.1.18 ( Revision: tonci.grgin@oracle.com-20110930151701-jfj14ddfq48ifkfq ) */SELECT @@session.auto_increment_increment"/> 
*************************** 3. row ***************************
text:   <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-08-20T14:07:41" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="12427046" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="select * from MM_CUSTOMER where upper(custcode) ='DECT'"/> 
*************************** 4. row ***************************
text:   <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-08-20T14:07:41" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="12427042" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="select * from MM_CUSTOMER where upper(custcode) ='MKTF'"/> 
*************************** 5. row ***************************
text:   <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-08-20T14:07:41" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="12427040" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="select * from MM_CUSTOMER where upper(custcode) ='FLYC'"/> 
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now i want to extract result in below format

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| ID                       | timestamp                        | text                                 |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| CONNECTION_ID="12427042" | TIMESTAMP="2013-08-20T14:07:41"  | "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'" |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

And the final result is sorted based on ID and grouped based on text like all set and then all selects and then updates....

**ALTERNATIVE:**

If possible please tell me how to load a file like below

```
<AUDIT>
      <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-08-20T14:07:41" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="12427046" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="select * from MM_CUSTOMER where upper(custcode) ='DECT'"/>
      <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-08-20T14:07:41" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="12427042" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="select * from MM_CUSTOMER where upper(custcode) ='MKTF'"/>
      <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-08-20T14:07:41" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="12427040" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="select * from MM_CUSTOMER where upper(custcode) ='FLYC'"/>
</AUDIT>
```

into the table like ..... with above mentioned criteria.

```
mysql> desc query;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID        | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| timestamp | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| text      | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can any one help me how to achieve this ?

Comment: Most databases suck at handling text, and suck even worse at XML.  This is why you parse your XML *before* stuffing it in a table, rather than storing records them as XML in a `text` field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you'd have these records already parsed, and you'd insert the value for each attribute rather than having to parse them after the fact.

However, if you're stuck with XML, and need to create a real table out of it, you might try using `ExtractValue()` to grab the pieces you want.

```
SELECT
    ExtractValue(`text`, '//@TIMESTAMP')     audit_time,
    ExtractValue(`text`, '//@CONNECTION_ID') connection_id,
    ExtractValue(`text`, '//@SQLTEXT')       sql
FROM query;
```

Note:  *do not do this on a regular basis.*  Ideally you'd do it once, to take those values and put them into a proper table.  Extracting from XML every time will murder your MySQL server's performance; not only do you end up parsing XML for every row, but without something outside the XML to filter or sort by, basically every operation forces a full table scan.

(Oh, and seriously.  How do you pick half your column names as keywords?  `TIMESTAMP` and `TEXT` are the names of SQL value types.)

Comment: I tried but the output is empty result ....**mysql> SELECT ExtractValue(`text`, '//@TIMESTAMP') audit_time,ExtractValue(`text`, '//@CONNECTION_ID') connection_id,ExtractValue(`text`, '//@SQLTEXT') sql_text FROM query;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)**

Comment: Wait a second...a SELECT shouldn't be affecting rows.  What the heck are you doing over there?  :P

Comment: Glad to help :)  Seriously, though:  Ditch the XML.  It's not worth the trouble overall.